# Can I travel to United Kingdom on carta di soggiorno with European Citizen member who’s having red passport Italian in June 2023

Tags: uk, italian-citizens

Can I travel to United Kingdom on carta di soggiorno with my husband who’s having european citizenship red passport Italian national in June 2023

Answer (score 3):

If you’re a non-EEA family member of an EU, EEA or Swiss citizen you need a valid national passport, and one of the following:

- an EU Settlement Scheme family permit
- a UK-issued EEA family permit
- a UK-issued biometric residence card

Effective 1 Jan 2021, you cannot use an Article 10 or Article 20 residence card issued by an EEA member state.

Source:

https://www.gov.uk/guidance/visiting-the-uk-as-an-eu-eea-or-swiss-citizen

https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card

You can check if you need a visa here https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa

Answer (score 2):

Whether you can travel to the UK without a visa depends on your own passport. You cannot use a residence permit as a travel document, and your husband's citizenship is irrelevant.

Comment: No last year people used to travel with family member who’s having European citizenship I want to confirm is this is valid for 2023 as well

Comment: @MadeehaFaisal You can check what entry documents you require for the UK here  https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa

Comment: @MadeehaFaisal Last year, no that was not possible.

Comment: @MadeehaFaisal documentary requirements for family members of EU citizens to travel to the UK were different when the UK was a member of the EU.  Now that the UK is no longer a member of the EU, your husband's citizenship is no longer relevant to the requirements you must meet.  This changed on January 1st 2021, at the end of the transition period, as noted in Traveller's answer.